# Android Studio asking for permission even though it is given in android manifest

Tags: android, permissions

my android manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.regnav.stilla" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

When I try to use the permission which is in the Android Manifest like this:

```
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

It will tell me that I need to do a permission check like so:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
```

I think this is strange as my android manifest already gives me permission to do this.. Am I doing something wrong?

I am editting the Android manifest in location:

Stilla/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running your app in Android 6.0?

Comment: And show your logcat.

Comment: I forgot to add that the code always goes inside the "if (checkselfpermission.. " even though I have given the permission in the AndroidManifest

Comment: The logcat is not showing anything as there are no errors

Comment: How can I check on which version of Android i am running this?

Comment: it showing any dialog to user for accept or denied the permission?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of Android Studio yesterday, I have all SDK's and am using an emulator

Comment: @Ramesh if it is showing that dialog, then you are on Android 6.0. Check my answer below

Comment: if permission is denied then use  requestPermissions for that particular permission

Comment: I don't want to ask for permission, I want the android manifest to give me permission as it should right?

Comment: The permission system has changed in android  Marshmallow.You have to check version also if it is android marshmallow use like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Android 6.0, checking whether you have a specific permission at any given point in the lifecycle of the app is mandatory. It is so because the user can revoke any single permission anytime he feels so and your app is **NOT** notified about this revoken permission.

Hence, before using any API which needs a permission, you should check whether you have by using the snippet you have posted. This is true even if you have that permission in your manifest.
Have a look at the [developer article](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

With Android Marshmallow the permission system was changed. Some permissions need to be requested at runtime. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is one of them. Please see [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Visit this: [Android Granular Permissions](http://arc.applause.com/cards/android-6-permissions-faq/). [Official Document](https://www.android.com/versions/marshmallow-6-0/)